# Unable to understand how both codes are similar

Tags: keras

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, input_shape=(16,)))
# Afterwards, we do automatic shape inference:
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4))

# This is identical to the following:
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(16,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8))
```

In the second code snippet, the second layer with 4 neurons is not specified, so how are both codes similar?

The first line of code adds a dense layer but with no units specified. So, how automatic shape inference can be applied here? If the number of units was given 8, then the input shape for the next layer would be (None,8).

Comment: They are not the same, the second version is missing the second dense layer. You are either missing some code, or whoever wrote this made a mistake, or this is just a misunderstanding (by "identical" they are only referring to how they supply the input shape).

Comment: What will be the input shape for the second layer in the first and second code snippets?